# Deleting certain pages of pdf and coverting back to NSMutableData

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, nsdata

I have a NSMutableData which contains pdf data. I want to delete certain pages from the pdf and return the pdf. I have tried creating the CGPDFContext, CGPDFPageRef, etc, but nothing really worked out. I have the below code, Can someone help me to fill the 3 steps.

```
-(NSMutableData *)deletePagesofPDF:(NSMutableData *)data withStartPage:(int)startpage withEndPage:(int)endpage{
NSData *data1               = data;
CFDataRef myPDFData       = (__bridge CFDataRef)data1;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf       = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);

//step 1 delete pages from startpage to endpage.
//step 2 save pdf
//step 3 convert pdf back to NSMutabledata

return data;
```

}

Edit 1

I have decided to change my strategy. Instead of deleting the pages, i am now creating a new pdf with only the pages i require from another PDF. Please see the code below, somehow it crashes while creating the pdf context. error is : address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file. I could not go past creating the context. Please correct me if there is something wrong after creating the context.

```
-(void)saveNSDataToPDFFile:(NSMutableData *)data{
NSData *data1               = data;
CFDataRef myPDFData       = (__bridge CFDataRef)data1;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf       = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
CGPDFPageRef newPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 2);

NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 850, 1100);

CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate((__bridge CGDataConsumerRef)(pdfData),&mediaBox,NULL);
CGPDFContextBeginPage (pdfContext,nil);
CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, newPage);
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);


[pdfData writeToFile:[self getDBPathPDf:@"Rajashekar.pdf"] atomically:YES];
```

}

EDIT 2

Sorry about my long post.
I can save the pdf file now without crashing but i cannot see the data inside the pdf. It just shows a medium sized box with "PDF" written inside it. Where am i going wrong?

```
-(void)saveNSDataToPDFFile:(NSMutableData *)data{
NSData *data1               = data;
CFDataRef myPDFData       = (__bridge CFDataRef)data1;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf       = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
CGPDFPageRef newPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 2);

NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 850, 1100);
CGDataConsumerRef consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)pdfData);
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer,&mediaBox,NULL);
if (pdfContext)
{

CGPDFContextBeginPage (pdfContext,nil);
CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, newPage);
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);


[pdfData writeToFile:[self getDBPathPDf:@"Rajashekar.pdf"] atomically:YES];
}
```

}

EDIT 3

Its working....:) i forgot to  CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext); before i closed the context.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet for steps 1, 2, and 3? If so, show that too.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for taking a look, Please see my edit.

Comment: could you explain your code a little more please ? :)